# Position divs in a tag cloud structure without overlap?

Tags: javascript, tags, tag-cloud

I wondered if someone could help.

I need to build a system that pulls numbers out of an array and displays them in a cloud like pattern (a range of different sizes and colours). I'm stumped on how to build a system to create the divs so they don't overlap and make a nice tight structure. Any pointers would be great.

Mock Up: http://img228.imageshack.us/my.php?image=example.png

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you should look at some of the tag cloud generation mechanisms flying around out there and see how they do their business.

Comment: Hi I have done but none that I can find do anything in regards to making the elements closer to one another so it looks visually better, typogrpahically. I will continue to dig however

Comment: If I were trying to do that, I'd start by playing with the margin, padding, line-height and letter-spacing CSS properties on the divs.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that the purpose of the [margin](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_margin.asp) in CSS?

I should imagine that setting a 1-px all-round margin will make sure that no div is less than a pixel from another.

Comment: The problem is the random placement, spacing, and sizing of each tag. CSS is still very grid-centric. Looking at his mockup, think of each tag enclosed in a box. All those gaps and overlaps that result would be tricky to pull off in CSS alone.